# Changing namespace root name with java Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I generated a webservice client from a WSDL with Java wsimport tool.
But when I use the Marshaller class to generate XML file, the root namespace gets the name `<Object xmlns:ns2="(...)"`.
Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Object xmlns:ns2="(...)"
```

I wanted it to have a specific name like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <myName xmlns:ns2="(...)"
```

---

That's the way I used Marshaller:

```
Writer w = new StringWriter();
JAXBElement<ObjectType> element = new ObjectFactory().createObject(evt);        

marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.marshal(element, w);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code working for me. This should work for you.

```
JAXBContext jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(classToBeBound.getClass());
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

Marshaller marshaller = jaxbCtx.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(The root of content tree to be marshalled, writer);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I did it. The only differece was in line "marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);"
And this line didn't help.

In my case "The root of content tree to be marshalled" is a JAXBElement:

"JAXBElement<ObjectType> element = new ObjectFactory().createObject(evt);"

And "evt" object is an ObjectType object where I set its properties to mount the final XML.